# Can we Pass Jquery Value in PHP Function of Block. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, jquery

I want to pass the value of **jquery** in **PHP function** is it possible to send the value. like for example I have a textbox and in textbox when the user add **5** then it instantly send to the php function after that when the user add **56** then the value is been send to the PHP function... I was trying but its not working for me.. my code is

```
<?php
$block->storeInAlgolic();
?>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal

        ){

        $("#order_search").keyup(function(){

            var textinput = $('#order_search').val().substring(0,20);

            <?php $block->getFromAlgolia('textinput'); ?>

            var client = algoliasearch(textinput);

            console.log(client);


            $("#textbox2").val(textinput);
            $("#textbox3").val(textinput);



        });

    });
</script>

<style>
    input[type=number] {
        width: 130px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: white;
        /*background-image: url('searchicon.png');*/
        background-position: 10px 10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    input[type=number]:focus {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Animated search form:</p>

<form type="POST">
    <input type="number" id="order_search" name="searchh" placeholder="Search Order by Order_ID">

    <br /><input type="text" id="textbox2"/><br>
    <br /><input type="text" id="textbox3"/>
</form>

</body>
```

the output is like
[image]

is there is any possible way to send Jquery instantly to php function?

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1** Create ajax request to your controller with below code

```
$("#order_search").keyup(function(){
    var textinput = $('#order_search').val().substring(0,20);                   
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('{route}/Index/Index') ?>',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            input_val : textinput
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**STEP 2** Create a controller with the above mentioned path with below code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    } 

    public function execute(){
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParam('input_val');

        //Your logic

        $response = $this->resultFactory
            ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
            ->setData([
                'status'  => "success"
            ]);

        return $response;
    }
}
```